# printf with multiple variable expansions + cuts

Tags: bash, printf, cut

I am trying to use printf to expand a variable (a long comma separated string) and cut certain fields out of the string. I can do it just fine printing only one field, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to add another cut.

The variable might look something like this: `blah1,blah2,blah3,...,blah7`

This for example works:

```
printf '%26s%-40s%s\n' '['$SELECT$i$RESET'] - ' ${dcarray[$i]} | cut -d"," -f1
```

Now I want to include both field 1 and 7, or 1 and 6, etc.

```
printf '%26s%-40s%-20s%-20s%s\n' '['$SELECT$i$RESET'] - ' ${dcarray[$i]} | cut -d"," -f1 ${dcarray[$i]} | cut -d"," -f7
```

This freaks out. I need to enclose them in quotes somehow. Thoughts?

Perhaps I should only expand the variable once and print the two fields I need.

***UPDATE***

Allow me to explain a little more.
The array "dcarray" has information such as URL, region, user, other, etc. all comma separated:

```
dcarray[1]="name,region,URL,other,...,etc"
```

The printf statement later in my script prints out each array element (for example):

```
[1] - US-TEXAS-1
[2] - US-TEXAS-2
[3] - US-TEXAS-3
```

The new addition will add the following:

```
[1] - US-TEXAS-1 - other info
[2] - US-TEXAS-2 - other info
[3] - US-TEXAS-3 - other info
```

I think I actually have two problems. I am still having trouble outputting the other info field into its own column. I think part of that problem is because I am messing up the printf column formatting too. Hopefully this makes the problem a little clearer.

Comment: "Freaks out" is not a very accurate error description ;-) ... You're doing `| cut -d"," -f1 ${dcarray[$i]}`, so that means you're piping data to `cut` **and** expect it to parse a file? It smells wrong. You can probably just remove `${dcarray[$i]}`?

Comment: Not quite following, but does `cut -f1,7` work to cut your first and seventh fields?  Likewise `cut -f1,6` for one and six?

Comment: i can't understand your question. isn't `echo $csv | cut -d"," -f1,7` as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching from `cut` to `awk` if possible:

```
SELECT=1;
i=2;
RESET=3;
dcarray[$i]="info1,info2"

awk -F, -v var="[$SELECT$i$RESET] -" '{ printf "%10s %-6s - %-6s\n", var, $1, $2 }' <<< "${dcarray[$i]}"

# outputs:
   [123] - info1  - info2
```

Comment: This essentially works, just need to do a bit of formatting. The columns dont seem to work this way and it shows the two fields separated by a comma. For example field1,field7. I think it still need to be enclosed in its own quotes so printf puts field7 in a separate column.